# Trying to match two date objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have following script

**Script**

```
$('#test1').click(function () {

    // Here are the two dates to compare
    var date1 = '29-10-2015';
    var date2 = '29-12-2015';
    var Targetvalue = parseFloat("1000000");
    var dealjson = '[{"dealdate":"25-12-2015","cost":200000},{"dealdate":"25-11-2015","cost":200000}]';

    // First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
    date1 = date1.split('-');
    date2 = date2.split('-');

    // Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
    date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1] - 1, date1[0]);
    date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1] - 1, date2[0]);
    var deals = JSON.parse(dealjson);
    var achieved = 0;

    while (date1 <= date2) {
        var next_day = new Date(date1);
        next_day.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
        achieved = 0;
        deals.forEach(function (deal) {
            var dealDate = deal.dealdate;
            dealDate = dealDate.split('-');
            dealDate = new Date(dealDate[2], dealDate[1] - 1, dealDate[0]);

            if (dealDate === date1) console.log("matched" + date);
        });

        date1 = next_day;
    }

});
```

I am trying to log in the console if both the date in the loop matches the date from Json array `dealjson`  although I have two dates which falls in between the date1 and date 2 but still the match is not happening

```
if (dealDate === date1) console.log("matched" + date);
```

Here is the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/k2pkv17a/10/)

Can any one help me out where is the mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check two dates for equality in JavaScript you have to get their "*number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00 UTC*" and compare these values.

To get this number, use the Date's `getTime()` method:

```
if (dealDate.getTime() === date1.getTime()) console.log("matched" + date);
```

See updated [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aforni/k2pkv17a/11/).

Comment: if I want to do this every month then what should I do ?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you want to check if two dates have the same month?

Comment: Umm I mean to say I should run the loop month wise , And I should log into console if the date falls into the related month .

Answer (score 0):

When you use `==` or `===` to compare `Date` instances, it will only be true for *the same `Date` instance*, not for *equivalent* `Date` instances.

To see if they have exactly the same time, use `+` or `getTime()`:

```
if (+dealDate === +date1)
// or
if (dealDate.getTime() === date1.getTime())
```

This isn't a problem with your other date relation, `<=`, because `<=` coerces its arguments to primitives. `==` and `===` don't do that if both sides are objects.

Comment: @T.JCrowder  can you instruct me How I can calculate total number of months between two given dates and then match the date from the json and log into console if the date match for that particular month

Answer (score 0):

You need to put date in timestamp.

```
var dc1=new Date(dealDate).getTime();
var dc2=new Date(date1).getTime();

 if(dc1===dc2) console.log("matched"+date1);
```

```js
$('#test1').click(function () {

    // Here are the two dates to compare
    var date1 = '29-10-2015';
    var date2 = '29-12-2015';
    var Targetvalue = parseFloat("1000000");
   var dealjson = '[{"dealdate":"25-12-2015","cost":200000},{"dealdate":"25-11-2015","cost":200000}]';

    // First we split the values to arrays date1[0] is the year, [1] the month and [2] the day
    date1 = date1.split('-');
    date2 = date2.split('-');
    
    // Now we convert the array to a Date object, which has several helpful methods
    date1 = new Date(date1[2], date1[1]-1, date1[0]);
    date2 = new Date(date2[2], date2[1]-1, date2[0]);
    var deals = JSON.parse(dealjson);
    var achieved = 0;

              while (date1 <= date2) {
                  var next_day = new Date(date1);
                  next_day.setDate(date1.getDate() + 1);
                  achieved = 0;
                  deals.forEach(function (deal) {
                      var dealDate = deal.dealdate;
                      dealDate = dealDate.split('-');
                      dealDate = new Date(dealDate[2], dealDate[1]-1, dealDate[0]);
                   
                      
                     var dc1=new Date(dealDate).getTime();
                     var dc2=new Date(date1).getTime();
                      
                      if(dc1==dc2){
                          console.log("matched"+date1);
                          $(".varianceData").text("matched"+date1);
                     }
                      
                     
                  });
     
              date1 = next_day;
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="test1">See the Tab Day </button>
<div class="varianceData"></div>
```